# Locate a key in Infinispan Distributed cluster

Tags: cluster-computing, infinispan

I have an Infinispan 7.1.1 cluster with 3 nodes with **numOwners = 2**. I cannot physically locate the location of a key within the cluster.
I am running infinispan in distributed mode + using the default cache, **ispn-cli.sh** CLI tool to connect.

**User Guide** says **locate** command does this job but the CLI tool is not recognizing this command.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: What error message are you getting? And make sure you select a cache first, with "cache <namedcache>".

Comment: These are my steps: sh $ISPN_HOME/bin/ispn-cli.sh --> connect <IP Address> --> container <container_name> --> cache <cache_name>.... -> locate <key>. Error Message : Unexpected command 'locate'. Type 'help --commands' for the list of supported commands.